# What is the specific function of the activation.jar, additional.jar, and mail.jar?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-manifest

Has anyone know what is the **specific** function of the Android library above (activation.jar, additional.jar, and mail.jar)?? as i know, this library is used for sending an email from Android device without user intervention but i don't know what is the specific function of that library..
Please tell me if you know about it.. thanks..

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android. Those JARs are from JavaMail, which has nothing to do with Android, other than some people have arranged to get JavaMail to run on Android.